# Rust library crashing on target armv7-linux-androideabi

Tags: android, flutter, dart, rust, android-ndk

The code for my Dart/Flutter application communicates with my native dynamic .so library, which is very performance intensive. The library is written in Rust. It works fine with targets `aarch64-linux-android` and `x86_64-linux-android`. When I run with target `armv7-linux-androideabi` the following line (Dart Code) crashes.

```
final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open("libmyimportantlib.so");
```

Here is the error message: Note that no code in the library is run, the crash occurs as soon as it is loaded (or tries to load).

```
F/libc    ( 7651): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 7742 (DartWorker)
```

Can anyone tell me why it works on all other targets but not `armv7-linux-androideabi`?

Comment: There's not enough information here to say what might be wrong. You say that no code is being run, but if your library contains a `JNI_OnLoad` function, then some code _will_ be run as soon as the library is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by downgrading the NDK version from 21 to 19. Apparently there is a problem with `libc` in the `armv7-linux-androideabi` target for version 20 and up.